# Where is the PHP on Windows Azure community?

Tags: php, azure

I'm doing production development with PHP on Windows Azure and I often feel alone with this topic and its wide range of problems.

Is there an active community focused on PHP on Windows Azure? A platform were it's possible to exchange experience, problems and solutions? And were to get as early as possible information about SDK updates etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a small but growing PHP on Windows Azure community. Most of the activity can be found on Stack Overflow, however you will be interested in these places as well

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/ - Documentation from Microsoft

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/ - The Microsoft team behind PHP on Windows Azure
https://twitter.com/#!/openatmicrosoft - Team Twitter account

http://phpazure.codeplex.com/discussions - PHP SDK forum which has activity also

Comment: Another good resource is Maarten Balliauw's blog at http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/category/PHP.aspx

Comment: One more good resource: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/tags/php/

Comment: Also here. Just ask your question and surely you will find an answer. The more questions all of you (us) ask, the more content to be indexed from the search engines there will be.

Comment: So the best thing is to post the questions here to reach all of your suggested resoureces?

Comment: Quite often yes. A large portion of people will see it here. Posting on the Codeplex site can work too, but it is not as active

Comment: I am a Windows Azure Evangelist focusing on the PHP Community. You'll see a variety of topics coming up on [my blog](http://blog.syntaxc4.net)

Answer (score 1):

The official windows azure development forum is here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/threads , posts are welcome!